# group a bunch of files by day

Tags: python, netcdf

I do have a bunch of files containing atmospheric measurements in one directory. Fileformat is NetCDF. Each file has a timestamp (variable 'basetime'). I can read all files and plot individual measurement events (temperature vs. altitude).
What I need to do next is "group the files by day" and plot all measurements taken at one single day together in one plot. Unfortunately I have no clue how to do that.
One idea is to use the variable 'measurement_day' as it is defined in the code below.
For each day I normally do have four different files containing temp. and altitude.
Ideally the data of those four different files should be grouped (e.g. for plotting)
I hope my question is clear. Can anyone please help me.

EDIT: I try to use a dictionary now but I have trouble to determine whether one entry already exists for one measurement day. Please see edited code below

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data ={} # was edited

for f in listdir(path):
    if isfile(join(path,f)):
        full_path = join(path,f)
        f = Dataset(full_path, 'r')
        basetime = f.variables['base_time'][:]
        altitude = f.variables['alt'][:]
        temp = f.variables['tdry'][:]
        actual_date =  strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(basetime))
        measurement_day =  strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime(basetime))
        # check if dict entries for day already exist, if not create empty dict  
        # and lists inside
        if len(data[measurement_day]) == 0:
             data[measurement_day] = {}
        else: pass
        if len(data[measurement_day]['temp']) == 0:
            data[measurement_day]['temp'] = []
            data[measurement_day]['altitude'] = []
        else: pass
```

I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):... if len(data[measurement_day]) == 0:
KeyError: '2009/05/28'

Comment: What is `Dataset`? Where does it come from?

Comment: We can't really tell how the data is structured until you answer Ethan Furman's question, but have you tried building a dictionary using `measurement_day` as the key?  You could have each value be a list of variables, or perhaps another dictionary (keys=altitude,temp,...), values = list of appropriate values

Comment: `Dataset` is class from the Python Module NetCDF4. It was imported before (`from NetCDF4 import Dataset`). Sorry for forgetting to add that line of code, too.

Comment: So you have four different files for each day? Do each of these files contain only the data for that day? If so, you could open all four of them with MFDataset(), and plot your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone please help me.

I will try.  Though I'm not totally clear on what you already have.

> I can read all files and plot individual measurement events
>   (temperature vs. altitude). What I need to do next is "group the files
>   by day" and plot all measurements taken at one single day together in
>   one plot.

From this, I am assuming that you know how to plot the information given a list of Datasets.  To get that list of Datasets, try something like this.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# a dictionary of lists that hold all the datasets from a given day
grouped_datasets = {}

for f in listdir(path):
    if isfile(join(path,f)):
        full_path = join(path,f)
        f = Dataset(full_path, 'r')
        basetime = f.variables['base_time'][:]
        altitude = f.variables['alt'][:]
        temp = f.variables['tdry'][:]
        actual_date =  strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(basetime))
        measurement_day =  strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime(basetime))

        # if we haven't encountered any datasets from this day yet...
        if measurement_day not in grouped_datasets:
            # add that day to our dict
            grouped_datasets[measurement_day] = []

        # now append our dataset to the correct day (list)
        grouped_datasets[measurement_day].append(f)
```

Now you have a dictionary keyed on measurement_day.  I'm not sure how you are graphing your data, so this is as far as I can get you.  Hope it helps, good luck.